# unit test a variable declaration inside ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to skill up in TDD, and I'm doing again every tutorials I could followed in Angular. 
But this time trying to unit tests them with 100% code coverage.

I've a stupid question, that I can't find the answer in [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing).
Can't find questions that are that simple in Stackoverflow neither.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  secondes: number;
  counterSubscritpion: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    const counter = interval(1000);
    const dummy = 'foo';

    this.counterSubscritpion = counter.subscribe(
      (value) => {
        this.secondes = value;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.counterSubscritpion.unsubscribe();
  }
```

My template is of course very simple :

```html
<p> nothing should appear here : {{dummy}} </p>
<p> whereas here should be {{secondes}} secondes </p>
```

So reading the documentation will help me testing `secondes` and `counterSubscritpion`...

**But how do I test that `counter` and `dummy` have been declared as well as their values ?**
because Karma's test coverage report tells me that I should test the `interval(1000) calls

So far i'm stuck with this :

```
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let routerOutlet: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  });

  it ('should declare dummy variable', () => {
    const appComp = new AppComponent();
    appComp.ngOnInit();
    // and so what ???
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using **TestBed** to create the *AppComponent*. *TestBed* configures and create a **test context**. It's possible to create routes, services and much more.

But you're not using it in your `it`. To get the created component by the TestBed, you can call `TestBed.get(AppComponent)` to retrieve it.

When creating a component outside *TestBed* (i.e. with `new`), you won't be able to access component's template. While it can be useful in some situations, it may not be in your case.

```
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let component: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = TestBed.get(AppComponent);
  });

  it ('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  ...
```

To test async mecanism, read https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/#_code_async_code_and_code_whenstable_code and https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/#_code_async_code_and_code_whenstable_code.
Which boils down to `async`, `fakeAsync`.

Comment: ok thank you for your reply: it help. I'll follow your advices on async code later on. Great article by the way.

But, I'm still not sure how I can unit-test the fact that, inside this component, I have a `dummy` variable, displayed in template, that has `'foo'` value (looks like three different tests on not async code to me, am I right ?)

Comment: I forgot to write about that :)
It's not possible to know if a variable is declared inside a function named `myFn` (could be `ngOnInit` in our case). Instead we can declare a variable outside `myFn` and check if the class field member has been changed (in other words, look for side effects). But as `dummy` variable inside the template is not a field member of AppComponent, it will never be reflected inside the template. It seems pointless to test it.